# CUDA: Wrapping device memory allocation in C++

Tags: c++, cuda, raii, placement-new

I'm starting to use CUDA at the moment and have to admit that I'm a bit disappointed with the C API. I understand the reasons for choosing C but had the language been based on C++ instead, several aspects would have been a lot simpler, e.g. device memory allocation (via `cudaMalloc`).

My plan was to do this myself, using overloaded `operator new` with placement `new` and RAII (two alternatives). I'm wondering if there are any caveats that I haven't noticed so far. The code *seems* to work but I'm still wondering about potential memory leaks.

The usage of the **RAII** code would be as follows:

```
CudaArray<float> device_data(SIZE);
// Use `device_data` as if it were a raw pointer.
```

Perhaps a class is overkill in this context (especially since you'd still have to use `cudaMemcpy`, the class only encapsulating RAII) so the other approach would be **placement `new`**:

```
float* device_data = new (cudaDevice) float[SIZE];
// Use `device_data` …
operator delete [](device_data, cudaDevice);
```

Here, `cudaDevice` merely acts as a tag to trigger the overload. However, since in normal placement `new` this would indicate the placement, I find the syntax oddly consistent and perhaps even preferable to using a class.

I'd appreciate criticism of every kind. Does somebody perhaps know if something in this direction is planned for the next version of CUDA (which, as I've heard, will improve its C++ support, whatever they mean by that).

So, my question is actually threefold:

1. Is my placement `new` overload semantically correct? Does it leak memory?
2. Does anybody have information about future CUDA developments that go in this general direction (let's face it: C interfaces in C++ s*ck)?
3. How can I take this further in a consistent manner (there are other APIs to consider, e.g. there's not only device memory but also a constant memory store and texture memory)?

---

```
// Singleton tag for CUDA device memory placement.
struct CudaDevice {
    static CudaDevice const& get() { return instance; }
private:
    static CudaDevice const instance;
    CudaDevice() { }
    CudaDevice(CudaDevice const&);
    CudaDevice& operator =(CudaDevice const&);
} const& cudaDevice = CudaDevice::get();

CudaDevice const CudaDevice::instance;

inline void* operator new [](std::size_t nbytes, CudaDevice const&) {
    void* ret;
    cudaMalloc(&ret, nbytes);
    return ret;
}

inline void operator delete [](void* p, CudaDevice const&) throw() {
    cudaFree(p);
}

template <typename T>
class CudaArray {
public:
    explicit
    CudaArray(std::size_t size) : size(size), data(new (cudaDevice) T[size]) { }

    operator T* () { return data; }

    ~CudaArray() {
        operator delete [](data, cudaDevice);
    }

private:
    std::size_t const size;
    T* const data;

    CudaArray(CudaArray const&);
    CudaArray& operator =(CudaArray const&);
};
```

About the singleton employed here: Yes, I'm aware of its drawbacks. However, these aren't relevant in this context. All I needed here was a small type tag that wasn't copyable. Everything else (i.e. multithreading considerations, time of initialization) don't apply.

Comment: Your implementation of singleton is dangerous at best. Please see the many other discussion about how to create a singleton in C++.

Comment: Yea, you're right. However, see my new clarification below the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would go with the placement new approach.  Then I would define a class that conforms to the std::allocator<> interface.  In theory, you could pass this class as a template parameter into std::vector<> and std::map<> and so forth.

Beware, I have heard that doing such things is fraught with difficulty, but at least you will learn a lot more about the STL this way.  And you do not need to re-invent your containers and algorithms.

Comment: Hadn't thought about an allocator. I've actually done this before so it shouldn't be too difficult.

Answer (score 7):

In the meantime there were some further developments (not so much in terms of the CUDA API, but at least in terms of projects attempting an STL-like approach to CUDA data management).

Most notably there is a project from NVIDIA research: [thrust](http://code.google.com/p/thrust)

Answer (score 2):

There are several projects that attempt something similar, for example [CUDPP](http://cudpp.github.io/).

In the meantime, however, I've implemented my own allocator and it works well and was straightforward (> 95% boilerplate code).

Comment: The stdcuda link is dead.

Comment: @einpoklum Thanks. Stands to reason that a 10-year-old answer would at some point be outdated. I’ve removed the link.

Answer (score 2):

> Does anybody have information about future CUDA developments that go in this general direction (let's face it: C interfaces in C++ s*ck)?

Yes, I've done something like that:

https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-api-wrappers/

> nVIDIA's Runtime API for CUDA is intended for use both in C and C++ code. As such, it uses a C-style API, the lower common denominator (with a few notable exceptions of templated function overloads).
>
> This library of wrappers around the Runtime API is intended to allow us to embrace many of the features of C++ (including some C++11) for using the runtime API - but without reducing expressivity or increasing the level of abstraction (as in, e.g., the Thrust library). Using cuda-api-wrappers, you still have your devices, streams, events and so on - but they will be more convenient to work with in more C++-idiomatic ways.